# How to parse quickfix incoming messages by tag?

Tags: python, quickfix

The way that most online tutorials parse incoming messages is :

```
symbol = fix.Symbol()
message.getField(symbol)
```

Is there any way that I can parse messages by tags?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
        field = quickfix.StringField(44)
        message.getField(field)
```

That's from [this doc page](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/receiving_messages.html), by the way.  It's the "No Type Safety" section at the bottom; click the "PYTHON" link to see the Python excerpt.

(Disclaimer: I know QF very well, but I barely know Python.  I can't help you much more on this particular question.)